# QR code php decode

Tags: php, qr-code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you read QR Codes in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899631/how-can-you-read-qr-codes-in-php)

Am sorry fr the question, but I am just a beginner and I know its possible to create a qr code generator with php and library available, but is it possible to decode a QR code with php?and if yes how?thanx for all answers...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899631/how-can-you-read-qr-codes-in-php

Answer (score 0):

There's already a couple of questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231741/qr-code-2d-barcode-coding-and-decoding-algorithms) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899631/how-can-you-read-qr-codes-in-php)) on SO that answer your question. It looks like there isn't a native PHP library but you can call an [external python decoder](http://www.pedemonte.eu/pyqr/index.py/pyqrhome) or [zxing](http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx).

Comment: thanx for the answer, can you tell me how to call external decoder then?thanx

Comment: Try [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).