# Read QR code with jQuery without flash for all operating sistem also android

Tags: android, jquery

I'm creating a website where user needs to use the webcam to read QR codes.

I found some great scripts to do it, for example this one http://www.scriptcam.com/demo_5.cfm

But this should also work with android, and it doesn't cause android does not support flash.

Does anyone know an alternative that works on any operating system? With jQuery?

Thank you.

Edited

I need to say that i already try this one http://www.webqr.com/index.html but is not working!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to upload the taken image to a server and return the result

Probably don't take pictures with the highest resolution
-> do the work on your server
[How can you read QR Codes in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899631/how-can-you-read-qr-codes-in-php)

Comment: Hi @Thomas Nordquist thank you for your answer, that will not work for me, i need to read the code with webcam, cause the codes are printed in cards.